# As written in an array variable in the language of Java? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tabs

I have a multi-language application. There are words in different languages. And I want to write the word for a specific language. Please help and then I will soon head to explode;

```
CharSequence Titles[]=
            {
            getResources().getString(R.string.titles),
            getResources().getString(R.string.result),
            getResources().getString(R.string.contacts)
            };
```

The error in this code

```
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Declaring Your View and Variables

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]=
        {
        getResources().getString(R.string.titles),
        getResources().getString(R.string.result),
        getResources().getString(R.string.contacts)
        };

int Numboftabs =3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Gradle Issued:

```
    03-19 14:59:42.882 5493-5493/? E/Zygote: v2
    03-19 14:59:42.882 5493-5493/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10140
    03-19 14:59:42.882 5493-5493/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
    03-19 14:59:42.882 5493-5493/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-A300F_5.0.2-1_0026
    03-19 14:59:42.882 5493-5493/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
    03-19 14:59:42.882 5493-5493/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    03-19 14:59:42.912 5493-5493/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
    03-19 14:59:42.932 5493-5493/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
    03-19 14:59:42.932 5493-5493/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
    03-19 14:59:43.042 5493-5493/com.android.example D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    03-19 14:59:43.042 5493-5493/com.android.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                             Process: com.android.example, PID: 5493                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at 

    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference                                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:85)                 at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                                           at com.android.example.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1656)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you have a null reference error. You are trying to get resources too early. Don't add any calls to methods in field declarations, since the object is not in a ready state at that time.

Move your `getString()` calls to the `onCreate()` method and they will work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem  is context value is null in getResources() Method

so change

```
    Context.getResources()
```

or

```
CharSequence Titles[];        
int Numboftabs =3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Titles[]=
    {
    getResources().getString(R.string.titles),
    getResources().getString(R.string.result),
    getResources().getString(R.string.contacts)
    };

   ----

   }
```